# Customizing HTML ouput of genhtml

Tags: linux, wxwidgets, lcov

I am using lcov and genhtml for code coverage. The output generated by genhtml has CSS style. The HTML window in wxWidgets 2.8.12 does not support CSS style HTML page.

Is it possible to get a normal HTML page using genhtml.

Regards
Johnnie

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to your question but [wxWebView](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_web_view.html) in wxWidgets 2.9 does support CSS so maybe you should consider upgrading to 2.9 and starting to use it.